# Paste existing values a certain number of times in respective rows based on the Column Count

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to apply the column count and paste the existing value in that row 8, or 4 times, etc.

I tried the Not IsEmpty function and loop to start at each row where the column is not empty, then paste a certain amount of times behind it.

Here's what I have and what I want it to look like.

Input
[image]

Desired Outcome
[image]

```vb
For X = 2 To 37
    For Y = 2 To 37
        For XX = 2 To Cells(XX, 1) 
            If IsEmpty(Cells(X, Y)) = False Then 
                Cells(X, Y).Copy Cells(X, XX+1) 
            End If
        Next XX
    Next Y
Next X
```

Answer (score 2):

### Fill to the Right

[image]

- Let's say that `n` is a value in column `A`: counting from the last column towards the left, it takes the `n-th` value to fill the `n-1` right-most columns with it.

```vb
Sub FillRight()

    ' Read.

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long, cCount As Long

    With ws.UsedRange
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1) ' without headers
        cCount = .Columns.Count
    End With

    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    ' Modify.
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, cNum As Long, cValue As Variant
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        If Len(CStr(Data(r, 1))) > 0 Then
            cNum = cCount - Data(r, 1) + 1
            cValue = Data(r, cNum)
            For c = cNum + 1 To cCount
                Data(r, c) = cValue
            Next c
        End If
    Next r

    ' Write.
       
    rg.Value = Data
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, Nothing happened when I tried it. Does this formula take into account that some cells are empty?

Comment: `If Len(CStr(Data(r, 1))) > 0` does that. As you can see from my screenshots, my data starts in cell `A1`. In the first row, there are headers. The code looks in column `A` for a number and according to this number, fills the data appropriately. If you could accurately share the information about the location of your data (your screenshots have no row or column headers), I'd be happy to modify the code so it would fit your needs. Also, from my screenshots, try to understand what the code does and use this information to better describe what's wrong with it and what's different about your data.

Comment: Hey, I just tried the code with a new sheet and it worked, but it seems like the code wants to fill the row to the end rather than stop based on the value in Column A. Let me post it real quick in a new comment

Comment: From your new screenshot, which you should have copied to your post, the row starting with `2` presents a case that wasn't presented in your original screenshot. Your original screenshot let me believe that the numbers in the first column present the position of the cell, you want to fill to the last column, from the last column (all values are aligned to the last column). Sorry, let me know if you want me to delete my post.